# Calculating Vs ​ in an amplifier circuit as a function of Ve ​

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to determine the relationship between the output voltage (Vs ) and the input voltage (Ve ) in an amplifier circuit with specific resistances. The circuit consists of an ideal operational amplifier and resistors
i find this :

$$V_2=V_a⋅(1+R_3/R_4)+(V_a−V_b)⋅R_4(R_2+R_3)+R_2R_3R_1$$

However, I'm uncertain about the correctness of this expression and would appreciate guidance on its accuracy or any possible mistakes in the calculation. Additionally, if there's a more efficient way to represent this relationship or if I've missed any considerations, I'd love to learn.

Any insights or assistance in determining the correct relationship between

Vs and Ve in this amplifier circuit would be greatly appreciated.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Greetings. To see the mistakes in your calculations, you need to post the calculations.

Comment: None of the terms on the right have the same units, so the equation is incorrect.

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695419/319836) is essentially a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the solution below using KVL and KCL.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use Thévenin equivalent of the R0,R1,R2 combination then you get

Rt = R0 + R1R2/(R1+R2)

Vt = (Vs*R2)/(R1+R2)

Then Vt/Ve = -(Rt/R) and

V2 = Vt*(R1+R2)/R2

So \$\frac {V_S}{V_e} = -\frac {R_0(R_1/R_2 +1) + R_1}{R}\$

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this. First, label stuff:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNIFh9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Due to the negative feedback, we can treat OA1 as an ideal voltage source, producing a potential \$V_S\$ at its output, with zero source impedance. This allows us to convert the system of \$V_S\$, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to their Thevenin equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fybX9c.png)</sup>

Replacing \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ with this equivalent, we now have this arrangement of resistances \$R_4\$, \$R_0\$ and \$R_T\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Zxmu.png)</sup>

Where:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_T &= R_1 \parallel R_2 \\ \\
&= \frac{R_1 R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

and:

$$ V_T = V_S \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$

Then we can establish potentials at Q and X. You could maybe derive these directly without reference to current \$I\$ along that path, using what you know about resistor potential dividers, but it might be easier to use Ohm's law to find current \$I\$, and go from there. Remember that the inverting input at node Q draws no current, so current is equal at all points along the chain:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \frac{V_E - V_T}{R_4 + R_0 + R_T} \\ \\
V_X &= V_T + IR_T \\ \\
V_Q &= V_X + IR_0 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The last equation we need comes from another consequence of negative feedback, that the op-amp produces whatever output \$V_S\$ is necessary to equalise its two inputs \$V_P\$ and \$V_Q\$. We have a virtual earth at Q:

$$ V_Q = V_P = 0V $$

I believe you now have all the equations needed to relate output \$V_S\$ and input \$V_E\$. That's some algebra that I'll leave for you.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit can be considered as an *inverting amplifier* (consisting of R, R0 and the op-amp) whose output voltage is attenuated by the R1-R2 *voltage divider* R2/(R1 + R2) times. Usually the voltage divider is much lower resistive than R0; so the total gain is approximately R0/R multiplied by (R1 + R2)/R2.

This trick is used to virtually increase the R0 resistance when it has to be too high but there is not such a resistor.

Sometimes R0, R1 and R2 are drawn in the shape of "T" letter, and the circuit is called " inverting amplifier with 'T' bridge in the negative feedback".

See also my [last answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695478/61398).